# Redirect from http to https behind a network loadblancer

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, network-load-balancer

I am trying to redirect http trafic from http to https on ec2 behind a network load balancer using htaccess

```
# aws rule for http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Above code does not work because network loadbalancer does not add x-forwarded header.

Comment: Have you considered setting Application Load Balancer as a target for NLB and creating a redirect action in ALB?

Comment: Please output all the request headers that your application server sees and add this to your question. If you want to do this in `.htaccess` then there _must_ be some header that indicates the protocol the client is using (if the request to your app server itself is not over HTTPS). Or, is this there a way to _enable_ the setting of this header in the LB?